# How to do migrations with TypeORM the right way?

Tags: typeorm

So, I've been trying to wrap my head around how to do migrations with TypeORM properly.

1. The first thing you learn is to use annotations (using synchronize=true). This is simple to use, but once you start changing things, you quickly notice how this is not going to work at all for production.
2. So the next thing to look at is migrations. With this you can upgrade an existing database, but it will fail with an empty database. Either you set synchronize=true and the db will be created in its final form, needing no migrations, causing migrations to fail. Or you set synchronize=false and the db will not be created, causing migrations to fail as well).
3. So unless I misunderstand something, the only way to prepare for a production environment with possible changes to the database is to create all the tables with migration scripts, but that leaves me wondering what I need all the annotation stuff for?

So my questions are:

- Any way to say "Hey, the db is obviously empty, so skip migrations and create from scratch"?
- Are there any other/better approaches?
- If I go with 3., some annotations seem to be duplicate (like onDelete, default values, etc.). So which annotation options can I remove since they will be declared during migrations?

Also: Are there any tutorials out there which actually face these real-world problems? All I seem to find are those, which are based on simple CRUD examples, where they don't seem to care about these kind of issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue you're struggling with. What exactly you want to achieve? What are the requirements or constraints? For example, I found the auto-generation migrations technique highly dangerous, therefore I write the migrations myself. The migrations that typeorm generates does not fit real world situations, for alter column it'll drop it and recreate.

Comment: What I want is to have an application, which can both be started with a blank state (no db setup yet) and with an existing state (which might need to be migrated).

In an ideal world, the blank state would be set up using the annotations only and ignore migrations. But that seems to be impossible. synchronize=true is no solution, as it's not capable of renames, etc (it doesn't know my intentions), so migrations from start (i.e. use migrations to create tables and later to modify them) is the only solution. But that creates duplicate code (migration + annotation).

Comment: I'm not generating migrations, I'm writing them by hand.